# Java Adding string to a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string

Hello I have been trying to add a `String` to a `String[]`. Here is what I have,

```
static String[] ipList = {"127.0.0.1", "173.57.51.111", "69.696.69.69"};
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String newIpGet = textfield.getText();
    try {
        for ( int  i = 0; i < Main.ipList.length; i++){
            Main.ipList[i+1] = newIpGet.toString(); // <---- *****
            Main.write(Main.ipList[i]);
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Main.amountOfIps = Main.amountOfIps + 1;

    System.out.println("Text Entered!");
    System.out.println("There are now " +Main.ipList.length + " Ips.");
    textfield.setVisible(false);

    label.setVisible(true);;
}
```

But, I keep getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because it wont let me make any new `String`s. I can't modify my declaration of `ipList[]` without a lot of modifications, what can I do?

Comment: Arrays have a fixed size.  You either need to create a new array at the new size and copy everything over to it or use an `ArrayList`, which essentially does this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java arrays are of a fixed length ([JLS-10.3. Array Creation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3) says, in part, the *array's length is available as a `final` instance variable `length`*). But you can use [`Arrays.copyOf(T[], int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-) to copy the array and make it one longer. As an example, something like,

```
String[] ipList = { "127.0.0.1" };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ipList));
int len = ipList.length;
ipList = Arrays.copyOf(ipList, len + 1);
ipList[len] = "192.168.2.1";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ipList));
```

Output is

```
[127.0.0.1]
[127.0.0.1, 192.168.2.1]
```

Comment: Another good option. 1+

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem! Do you happen to know how to only capture only 1 enter from acntionPerformed? It keeps duplicating it multiple times?

Comment: Remove the loop. You only want to add it once.

Answer (score 7):

What do you think will happen here:

```
for ( int  i = 0; i < Main.ipList.length; i++){
    Main.ipList[i+1] = newIpGet.toString();
    Main.write(Main.ipList[i]);
}
```

when `i == Main.ipList.length - 1`, and you try to access `Main.ipList[i + 1]` which equals `Main.ipList[Main.ipList.length]`? This is guaranteed to throw the exception that you're seeing.

You state:

> "I cant really change my declaring of ipList[] or it would mess up my whole project."

Sometimes there are times when you just have to take the plunge and mess everything up, and this looks to be one of them. If you need an expandable array, don't use an array, but rather an `ArrayList<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

You also just could use an `ArrayList<String>` from the `java.util` package! These are of variable length and therefore not immuatable in length like an `String[]` is. Furthermore they do it "on the fly" when you add or remove something.